# Handling Javascript Event Order in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, event-handling

How does IE handle event propagation and is there any way to know which HTML element is currently handling the element?
The problem is something like this.

```
<div id="someDiv">
    <input type="text" id="txtName" onblur="someFunction()">
    <img src="/url" id="imgIcon" onclick="someFunction()"/>
</div>

<script>
    function someFunction()
    {
    // Open a popup
    }
</script>
```

Now, when the user enters something in the textbox and clicks on imgIcon, someFunction is called twice and the popup is opened. How should I handle the event here so as to call someFunction() only once i.e. as if it got triggered from only one of the events?

Answer (score 1):

You have called this function on both the event on blur of text box and on click of the image so when you click on the image it lost the focus from text box so event is triggered at the both time so you can check do you need to call it on both event or any of the event?

you can check whether the function is called then do not process further using a boolean variable in javascript but it will not a good solution.

Comment: Yes, I need to call the same function on both the events and that is the cause of the whole problem. If two functions were to be called, a boolean flag would have helped, but agian as you said, that is not a good solution.

Comment: you can do a thing when the text blurs you can disable image. somefunction is being called at the blur so do you still need to call it on click?

Comment: Well, thats a solution, but will work only on once. If user stays on the page and clicks on the image to call the function again, the event wont be fired (as we had disabled the img on blur). One workaround to this might have been that when user closes the popup (opened by somefunction(), onblur, the disbled image could have been enabled by making img.diabled = flase), but this wont work either because as the image had been disabled, it becomes undefined now and cant be accessed by javascript, Long comment, hope i have been clear.

Comment: making img.diabled = flase do not leads to undefine image you can enable it using javascript.

Comment: Well, that's true, my bad. But the problem of enabling the img still remains.